# How can I find out if a class that I use in my app is private or not?

Tags: ios

How can I find out if a class that I use in my app is private or not? Has this been specified in the class documentation?

Comment: If it's private it won't be _in_ the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Create an archive of your app as you would if you were going to submit it to iTunes Connect. Open up Xcode's Organizer window, and run "Validate" on the archive. It will generate a warning if you have called a private API.